# Python: E1136:Value 'self.exchange.get_portfolio' is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, algorithm, bitmex

```
def get_portfolio(self):
        contracts = settings.CONTRACTS
        portfolio = {}
        for symbol in contracts:
            position = self.bitmex.position(symbol=symbol)
            instrument = self.bitmex.instrument(symbol=symbol)

        if instrument['isQuanto']:
            future_type = "Quanto"
        elif instrument['isInverse']:
            future_type = "Inverse"
        elif not instrument['isQuanto'] and not instrument['isInverse']:
            future_type = "Linear"
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Unknown future type; not quanto or inverse: %s" % instrument['symbol'])

        if instrument['underlyingToSettleMultiplier'] is None:
            multiplier = float(instrument['multiplier']) / float(instrument['quoteToSettleMultiplier'])
        else:
            multiplier = float(instrument['multiplier']) / float(instrument['underlyingToSettleMultiplier'])

        portfolio[symbol] = {
            "currentQty": float(position['currentQty']),
            "futureType": future_type,
            "multiplier": multiplier,
            "markPrice": float(instrument['markPrice']),
            "spot": float(instrument['indicativeSettlePrice'])
        }

    return portfolio



qty = self.exchange.get_portfolio['currentQty']()
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong when I am calling the get_portfolio function because I keep getting this error message:

```
E1136:Value 'self.exchange.get_portfolio' is unsubscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a little mistake in the call:

`self.exchange.get_portfolio` is a function, so you first have to call it and *then* you can reference the entries from the returned dict.

Oh I just saw, that you also have to insert your `symbol` before:

```
qty = self.exchange.get_portfolio()[<YOUR_SYMBOL>]['currentQty']
```

If you don't know the symbols, you can use the `keys` function which lists all the keys of your dict:

```
port = self.exchange.get_portfolio()
port_keys = port.keys()
qty = port[port_keys[<SOME KEY NUMBER>]]['currentQty']
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, so others know it's solved ;)

Comment: @VarunReddy user8408080 He may not know the symbol's value, see my working answer below

Comment: You think I should also point out, that there is a `keys` function?

Comment: @user8408080 Actually I can't test it as you neither, but as SYMBOL has been created inside the function caller may not know its value.

Comment: I have changed it to match your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as follows:

```
qty = self.exchange.get_portfolio()
qty = qty[qty.keys()[0]]['currentQty']
```

or in a single row:

```
qty = self.exchange.get_portfolio()[self.exchange.get_portfolio().keys()[0]]['currentQty']
```